# Writing an infinite loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I am writing code that should create an infinite loop, but is currently terminating unexpectedly.
When I either type in 'Y' for yes or 'N' for no, this code should enter a non-terminating loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Math_Island_XTENDED_Final
{
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Declarations
        int Bignumber;
        int Mednumber;
        int Smallnumber;
        double addition;
        double subtraction;
        double multiplcation;
        double division;
        double sphere_radius1;
        double sphere_radius2;
        double sphere_radius3;
        double rectangle_measurements;
        char repeat;
        String input;

        System.out.println("Welcome to Math Island :D ! ");
        System.out.println("We will use some numbers for our Formula ! ");
        System.out.println("1 rule, NO DECIMALS !! ");
        System.out.println("Please Pick a # from 1 to 100 NOW!! ");
        Bignumber = sc.nextInt();        
        System.out.print("Please Pick a # from 1 to 20 NOW!! ");
        Mednumber = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please Pick a # from 1 to 5 NOW!! ");
        Smallnumber = sc.nextInt();

        //Results

        addition = Bignumber + Mednumber + Smallnumber;
        subtraction = Bignumber - Mednumber - Smallnumber; 
        multiplcation = Bignumber * Mednumber * Smallnumber;
        division = Bignumber / Mednumber / Smallnumber;
        sphere_radius1 = Bignumber * 3.14 * 3.14;
        sphere_radius2 = Mednumber *  3.14 * 3.14;
        sphere_radius3 = Smallnumber *  3.14 * 3.14;
        rectangle_measurements = Bignumber * Mednumber * Smallnumber;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        //results 2
        System.out.println(" Your addition answer would be " + addition);
        System.out.println(" Your subtraction answer would be " + subtraction);
        System.out.println(" Your multiplcation answer would be " + multiplcation);
        System.out.println(" Your division answer would be " + division);
        System.out.println(" Your first sphere answer would be " + sphere_radius1);
        System.out.println(" Your second sphere answer would be " + sphere_radius2);
        System.out.println(" Your third sphere answer would be " + sphere_radius3);
        System.out.println(" Your recangle size  would be " + rectangle_measurements+ " in cubic Feet");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Would you like to Play again  ? ");
        System.out.println("Y for yes, & N  for no " );

        input = keyboard.nextLine(); 
        repeat = input.charAt(0);

        while (repeat == 'Y');
            System.out.println();

        while (repeat == 'N');
            System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Writing an infinite loop isn't difficult. Just write `while(true){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encase the entire code in a `while` loop

define `repeat` as a boolean before the while loop- set it as True

then replace

```
while (repeat == 'Y') {
      System.out.println();
}

while (repeat == 'N') {
      System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");

}
```

with an `if` statement that checks if the user input is "n", in which case change `repeat` to False. Otherwise keep `repeat` as True.

Also- lots of syntax errors in the code- clean those up and you should be fine

Answer (score 3):

You have semicolons after your while loops:

```
while (repeat == 'Y'); // <-- Right here
      System.out.println();
```

If you remove it, you should get an infinite loop if `repeat == 'Y'` is true.

The same goes for the other loop.  Just make sure you use braces around the code that you want to loop over:

```
while (repeat == 'Y')
      System.out.println();


while (repeat == 'N') {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

If you want to use the loop to play the game again, I would recommend using a `do/while` loop, since you want to play at least once:

```
do {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Math Island :D ! ");
        System.out.println("We will use some numbers for our Formula ! ");
        System.out.println("1 rule, NO DECIMALS !! ");
        System.out.println("Please Pick a # from 1 to 100 NOW!! ");
        Bignumber = sc.nextInt();        
        System.out.print("Please Pick a # from 1 to 20 NOW!! ");
        Mednumber = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please Pick a # from 1 to 5 NOW!! ");
        Smallnumber = sc.nextInt();

        //Results

        addition = Bignumber + Mednumber + Smallnumber;
        subtraction = Bignumber - Mednumber - Smallnumber; 
        multiplcation = Bignumber * Mednumber * Smallnumber;
        division = Bignumber / Mednumber / Smallnumber;
        sphere_radius1 = Bignumber * 3.14 * 3.14;
        sphere_radius2 = Mednumber *  3.14 * 3.14;
        sphere_radius3 = Smallnumber *  3.14 * 3.14;
        rectangle_measurements = Bignumber * Mednumber * Smallnumber;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        //results 2
        System.out.println(" Your addition answer would be " + addition);
        System.out.println(" Your subtraction answer would be " + subtraction);
        System.out.println(" Your multiplcation answer would be " + multiplcation);
        System.out.println(" Your division answer would be " + division);
        System.out.println(" Your first sphere answer would be " + sphere_radius1);
        System.out.println(" Your second sphere answer would be " + sphere_radius2);
        System.out.println(" Your third sphere answer would be " + sphere_radius3);
        System.out.println(" Your recangle size  would be " + rectangle_measurements+ " in cubic Feet");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Would you like to Play again  ? ");
        System.out.println("Y for yes, & N  for no " );

        input = keyboard.nextLine(); 
        repeat = input.charAt(0);

} while (repeat == 'y');

System.out.println("Goodbye!");*
```

Answer (score 1):

Take all the code you want to repeat and put it inside of its own function:

```
void myMathGame() {
    //code for one round: setup, get user input, calculate values, print them
}
```

Then simply construct an unconditional infinite loop inside of your main function which you break if the user doesn't want another round:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        myMathGame();

        System.out.println("Would you like to Play again? (Y/N) ");
        if (keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0) != "Y") {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```